# Crash of Qt program in windows when starts a qthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I created a Qt application whitch uses `QThreadPool` and `QThread`.
It runs & works in Linux without prblem but in windows just before starting a thread it crashes and gives this message:

[image: Crach message]

my code of `QThreadPool` is:
(`tableRowProcessorTask` is a `QRunnable`)

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(4);
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        tableRowProcessorTask *t=new tableRowProcessorTask(i);
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(t);
}
```

and my code for `QThread` is:
(`QThread` is a `QObject`)

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
fileLoaderForAnimationWorker* worker = new fileLoaderForAnimationWorker(File.fileName());
worker->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
```

What causes this?

I'm using Qt 5.5.1 on windows 10

Comment: For crashes you need to at least post the type of crash and include a stack trace.

Comment: @MrEricSir: it gives nothing more than that! how can I find the type?

Comment: Your debugger will tell you.

Comment: @MrEricSir: no unfortunately debugger prints nothing; anyway i found the problem; I was tring to load a QWidget in QThread which is illegal; problem solved; thanks